# Anylogic: Declare parameter of type ArrayList

Tags: anylogic

I'm building a class (sorry - Agent) that will work with a set of Tank objects (Fluid Library) - doing things like monitoring individual levels or total level of all tanks, reporting on levels and initiating actions based on levels - things of that nature. For argument's sake let's call it a "TankMonitor" agent.
Ideally I'd like to be able to define a Parameter in my "TankMonitor" agent that allows me to define the tanks of interest when I place a TankMonitor in main. I have tried to define the type of the parameter as Other - `ArrayList<Tank>` however I don't know how to set up the next step to allow me to populate the ArrayList of Tanks when I put an instance of this agent in main.  My preference would be to have a list type control to populate the ArrayList - much like the way the AnyLogic Seize block allows you to specify multiple resource pools to choose from.

Has anyone attempted this before and been successful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible as follows:

1. Change the type to "Other" and then 'Tank[]' , i.e. an Array of Tanks
2. Change the control type to "one-dimensional array"

Example below. Now you have the same UI to pre-define tanks at design time for your agent instance.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Benjamin's perfect answer, I'd just add the manual workaround, which is not needed here but can be useful when the parameter in question has a more complicated structure than covered by the pre-made controls, say a list of lists, a map, or similar.

In such a case, the Control Type is still Text, and populating it in an instance happens by pointing it to a new object of the parameter's type. E.g. for an  `ArrayList<Tank>` parameter, you might instantiate a new ArrayList object, which you fill with a list of objects like so:
`new ArrayList<Tank>(Arrays.asList(tankA, tankB))`

In the Java code, whatever is written into that text box will end up on the right side of a parameter assignment statement in the embedded Agent instance's auto-generated parameter setup function. Therefore, multi-statement code won't work in this spot. Instead, if the process of building the parameter value doesn't fit neatly into a single expression, you can hide the code in a function which returns the desired object, and call that from the parameter's text box.

Comment: Exactly!  This is a failsafe option that works for everything.  Now if I could get something to look nice for a 2D array then we'd have all bases covered - no need to respond :)